# How to give static title and image in code while sharing details to whatsapp (og)

Tags: php, web, whatsapp, whatsapi

I am doing share the details to WhatsApp from the website, it is working like I am giving https://www.facebook.com, which means it is automatically taking the:

1. Title
2. description
3. image

### This not my requirement

I want to give my `Title` and 'description' and `image`> The below code I am trying like that but I am not able share the details what I am expecting

```
<html>
<head>
<meta property="og:title" content="Testing" />
<meta property="og:description" content="How to change the address" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.facebook.com/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://teja8.kuikr.com/o1/20180330/ak_1762149779-1522418417.jpg" />
</head>
</html>

 <a href="https://web.whatsapp.com/send?text=https://www.facebook.com/">Share To WhatsApp</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You share facebook.com to WhatsApp, so WhatsApp get meta info from facebook.

You need change this

```
 <a href="https://web.whatsapp.com/send?text=<your website>">Share To WhatsApp</a>
```

Comment: I understand , how we can give static `title` and 'image' , suppose we are given domain name means it will take details (`Title` and `Image`) from given website

Comment: sorry, I don't really understand( You want share facebook.com link with your title and image?

Comment: Yes,Exactly same

Comment: sorry, I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Actually i will give my domain only , but every time title and image it will come dynamic,Let say i having 10 events,That means 10 events having different different `title  and  image`, suppose i am want to share particular event means , i have to send that image to whatsapp

Comment: Now your are getting my question ?

Comment: For different image and title u need share different url. site.com/event-1/ site.com/event-2/ or mb site.com/?event=1 etc

Comment: Yes,anyhow `eventId=2`,`eventId=3` like this URl will change

Comment: You are understanding my requirement means,kindly do the need full for me(Update your code),because i spent lot of time but i didn't get my answer

Comment: how u render ur html? You have backend or just simple html files?

Comment: Make it html only(different title and image) ,after that i will make dynamic like based on my `eventId`

Comment: @ Bogdan, It Possible Mr  Bogdan, i am waiting for your response please

Comment: `<html>
<head>
<meta property="og:title" content="Title Event 1" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Descr Event 1" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://example.comt/?event=1" />
<meta property="og:image" content=https://example.com/event_1.jpeg" />
</head>
</html>

 <a href="https://web.whatsapp.com/send?text=https://example.com/?event=1">Share To WhatsApp</a>`

Comment: there is problem with inline formatting( But it simple. when u open https://example.com/?event=1 u must see in og content for event 1. Different content in each og meta for diferent url.